# How to tie in the back end?

Tags: node.js, backend, dialogflow-es, sendmessage

I'm trying to send a simple text message with `pickupLocation` info from user input to a cell phone as a text. I retrieved a code snipped for message from the Twilio website, but I don't think I have the syntax correct to create the message in the `index.js` of Fulfillment.

I created a function to send the message and I think I'm on the right track but I can't seem to get the code to work properly and I cannot find a clear example of syntax to create the function for the text.

Can anyone help me? Here is the code I have so far and its not working when I deploy. Any assistance would be WONDERFUL! :) I have attached the snipped of code that I put together.

[image]

Comment: Please put code here instead of an image

Comment: Is a request sent from Dialogflow to your webhook?  Can you post any logs?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be careful about posting your `sid` and `authToken` in here.

1. You don't need to define all of those variables as `const`.
2. `Location(Date.parse(agent.parameters.pickupLocation))`

Surely the pickup location isn't a date? I think your pickup location will be wrong from that every time.

Are you logging anything besides the message sid? What is happening when that functions runs?